# How to pass method as parameter and return for loop in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

The issue with my code lies with the method "makeSomeNoise". I want to pass the method "animals" to "makeSomeNoise" because I want to pass the list of animals as the parameter and then return the list of strings containing the noises of each animal (class) in the input.

```
abstract class Animal(name: String) {
def sound(): String
override def toString: Animal
}

class Cat(var name: String)
extends Animal(name)
{
override def sound() = {
"meow"
}
}

class Dog(var name: String)
extends Animal(name){
override def sound() = {
    "woof"
}
}

object Park{
def animals() = {
    val a =List(new Dog("Snoopy"), new Dog("Finn"), new Cat("Garfield"),new Cat("Morris"))
    a
}
def makeSomeNoise(Park.animals()) = {
    for (i<-animals){
    val b = List() :+ i.sound
    b
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should modify your original question **only** to clarify it. Please don't update it in such a way that the submitted answers no longer make sense.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I forgotted to include the abstract nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you use `def` for values that are more naturally `val`.

Does this get at what you're after?

```
abstract class Animal(name: String) {
  def sound(): String
  override def toString = "Animal"
}

class Cat(var name: String) extends Animal(name) {
  override def sound() = "meow"
}

class Dog(var name: String) extends Animal(name) {
  override def sound() = "woof"
}

object Park{
  def animals() =
    List(new Dog("Snoopy"), new Dog("Finn"), new Cat("Garfield"),new Cat("Morris"))

  def makeSomeNoise(lst :List[Animal]) :List[String] = lst.map(_.sound())
}

Park.makeSomeNoise(Park.animals())  
//res0: List[String] = List(woof, woof, meow, meow)
```

Comment: For my task, method animals has to stay the same and the result of the method animals has to be passed to method makeSomeNoise as a parameter.

Comment: @Anonymous; modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to make it a default parameter and use map for iteration and it will return a Type that is defined by your map result.

```
def makeSomeNoise(animals: List[Animal] = Park.animals()) = {
    animals.map(animal => animal.sound)
}
```